# Breaking up long switch

Tags: java, refactoring

I have this code:

```
public void addSkillXp(SkillType attribute, int value) {
    final SkillDatabaseEntity skillDatabaseEntity = skillValueCache.getEntity();

    switch (attribute) {
        case TWO_HANDED_CRUSHING_WEAPONS:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(value);

            skillMapper.addTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        case ONE_HANDED_CRUSHING_WEAPONS:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(value);

            skillMapper.addOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        case TWO_HANDED_AXES:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setTwoHandedAxesXp(value);

            skillMapper.addTwoHandedAxesXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        case ONE_HANDED_AXES:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setOneHandedAxesXp(value);

            skillMapper.addOneHandedAxesXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        case THROWING_WEAPONS:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setThrowingWeaponsXp(value);

            skillMapper.addThrowingWeaponsXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        case FISTFIGHT:
            skillDatabaseEntity.setFistfightXp(value);

            skillMapper.addFistfightXp(userEntity.getId(), value);
            break;
        ...
}
```

The switch is goes on for more 20 cases. The SkillDatabaseEntity is a simple DAO class:

```
public class SkillDatabaseEntity {

    private int twoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    private int oneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    private int twoHandedAxesXp;
    private int oneHandedAxesXp;
    private int throwingWeaponsXp;
    private int fistfightXp;
    private int longswordsXp;
    private int shortswordsXp;
    private int polearmsXp;
    private int daggersXp;
    private int longbowsXp;
    private int showrtbowsXp;
    private int crossbowsXp;
    private int lightArmorXp;
    private int heavyArmorXp;
    private int robeArmorXp;
    private int armorlessDefenseXp;
    private int shieldDefenseXp;
    private int staffsXp;
    private int wandsXp;
    private int spectresXp;
    private int scavengingXp;
    private int cookingXp;

    public int getTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp() {
        return twoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    }

    public void setTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(int twoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp) {
        this.twoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp = twoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    }

    public int getOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp() {
        return oneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    }

    public void setOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(int oneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp) {
        this.oneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp = oneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp;
    }

    public int getTwoHandedAxesXp() {
        return twoHandedAxesXp;
    }

    public void setTwoHandedAxesXp(int twoHandedAxesXp) {
        this.twoHandedAxesXp = twoHandedAxesXp;
    }

    public int getOneHandedAxesXp() {
        return oneHandedAxesXp;
    }

    public void setOneHandedAxesXp(int oneHandedAxesXp) {
        this.oneHandedAxesXp = oneHandedAxesXp;
    }

    public int getThrowingWeaponsXp() {
        return throwingWeaponsXp;
    }

    public void setThrowingWeaponsXp(int throwingWeaponsXp) {
        this.throwingWeaponsXp = throwingWeaponsXp;
    }
    ...
}
```

I need to add removeSkillXp but really want to avoid this huge switch and also if I'm here I want to improve that old scwitch too. How can I do that?

What I have as a plan is to create a new class like this:

SkillModifier:

- increaseExperience(UserEntity, value)
- decreaseExperience(UserEntity, value)
- getExperience(UserEntity, value)
- getSupportedSkillType()

And create an instance of this class for every case in the switch, add the instances into a map (This can be easily done with Spring DI) and use something like this:

```
public void addSkillXp(SkillType attribute, int value) {
    skillMap.get(attribute).increaseExperience(userEntity, value);
}
```

Can this work? Or is there a better pattern to do?

Answer (score 1):

The whole switch seems redundant because each case does the same thing. Why not create an abstract class weapon which has a method increaseXP and is extended by each weapon class (2h etc.). 
In this way the implementation is in the abstract class and the other sub-classes just call .increaseXP. 
 
By the way the database class seems unnecessary, just keep a list / array of weapons for each player.

Some more background info see:

https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: Sadly the database class is a must have to use the database framework MyBatis. :S Without the database class the whole thing woud be a "walk in the park".

Answer (score 1):

If you move the functionality from the code into the object, things get much easier.

For example:

```
enum SkillType {
    TWO_HANDED_CRUSHING_WEAPONS {
        @Override
        void updateEntity(SkillDatabaseEntity entity, int value) {
            entity.setTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(value);
        }

        @Override
        void mapSkill(SkillMapper mapper, int userId, int value) {
            mapper.addTwoHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(userId, value);

        }
    },
    ONE_HANDED_CRUSHING_WEAPONS {
        @Override
        void updateEntity(SkillDatabaseEntity entity, int value) {
            entity.addOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(value);
        }

        @Override
        void mapSkill(SkillMapper mapper, int userId, int value) {
            mapper.addOneHandedCrushingWeaponsXp(userId, value);

        }
    },
    TWO_HANDED_AXES {
        @Override
        void updateEntity(SkillDatabaseEntity entity, int value) {
            entity.setTwoHandedAxesXp(value);
        }
        @Override
        void mapSkill(SkillMapper mapper, int userId, int value) {
            mapper.addTwoHandedAxesXp(userId, value);

        }
    };

    abstract void updateEntity(SkillDatabaseEntity entity, int value);

    abstract void mapSkill(SkillMapper mapper, int userId, int value);
}

public void addSkillXp(SkillType skill, int value) {
    final SkillDatabaseEntity skillDatabaseEntity = skillValueCache.getEntity();
    skill.updateEntity(skillDatabaseEntity, value);
    skill.mapSkill(skillMapper, userEntity.getId(), value);
}
```

Here `addSkillXp` has become just three lines of code.

Another elegant benefit to this is that all of the skill-reelated code is in the same `enum`.

Comment: Well, I don't want to add such a functionality to my enums. I don't want my enums to know about SkillMappers and DAO objects etc.

Comment: @LakatosGyula - Why?

Comment: Cohesion. The enum identifies a skill. I don't want it to do all different kind of things with the skill. They can easily grow in size very fast wehn I start adding more functionality. Also I can't control a creation of the enums. I can't inject/autowire the skillMapper in the constuctor, I can only pass it as a variable. What happens when I need another mappers/services for the calculations? The variable count would grow quickly. 3 input variable is sometimes acceptable, 4 is a LOT for me.